# Blocking access to folder at specific hours

Tags: windows-8.1, blocking, user-folders

I am quite sure this question has been asked already, but I can't find the (removed?) post anymore.

How can I block the access to some folders (i.e music, videos...) on my laptop at specific hours under Windows 8.1?

**EDIT** To be clear: I want to *prevent myself* to access specific folder at specific (working) hours. No one else uses my laptop, so there are no other accounts.

The reason for this is I have ADHD, I get easily distracted from work and study: I have already blocked sites like 9gag, youtube and such; if I could to block folder containing music, movies etc... that would help a lot

Comment: Do you mean by account, or are you trying to block yourself?

Comment: Good edit, but can you explain why as well. I mean it would help us to come up with solutions. As it is, the obvious answer is for you to look at the time first :)

Comment: Is this the thread? http://superuser.com/questions/417373/is-there-a-way-to-lock-folder-and-all-files-inside-for-specific-time

Comment: @LJD200 No, but that *is* very useful. I just don't know how to "*use a scheduled task to remove the ACL using CACLS.EXE*"

Comment: @mattiav27 I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cobbled together a solution with info from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/417373/is-there-a-way-to-lock-folder-and-all-files-inside-for-specific-time) on Super User and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows) on Stack Overflow.

1. Create a folder that is to be locked/unlocked.
2. Create two bat scripts in your Documents in the folder above the one that is to be locked/unlocked using Notepad. Name one 'unlockfolder.bat' and type the following into the file: `icacls "*NAME OF FOLDER TO BE LOCKED*" /grant *YOUR USERNAME*:(OI)(CI)F`. Name the other file 'lockfolder.bat' and type the following into the file: `icacls "*NAME OF FOLDER TO BE LOCKED*" /deny *YOUR USERNAME*:(OI)(CI)F`
3. Open Task Scheduler and right click on `Task Scheduler Library`.
4. Click on `Create Task`.
5. On the General screen, edit the options to make them look like this screenshot. In the bit I've blanked out, ensure your user is selected (it should be by default).
   [image: Task General Screenshot]
6. Click `Triggers` and then `New`.
7. Ensure `On a schedule` is selected and then click `Daily` and then set the time to the time when you wish the folder to be locked daily.
8. Press `OK`.
9. Click `Actions` and ensure `Start a program` is selected. Click `Browse` and navigate to the 'lockfolder.bat' script you made earlier. Double click the script.
10. Press `OK` and `OK` again.
11. Repeat steps 3-10 once more but call the script 'Unlock Folder', select the time you wish the folder to be unlocked at everyday and select the 'unlockfolder.bat' script.

That's it! Every day, at the times you specified the folder will lock and unlock.

You can hide the scripts so they aren't shown in Windows Explorer and Task Scheduler will still run them fine. Note that you'll still be able to access them by unhiding them.

For a breakdown of the two command in the scripts, see the Stack Overflow thread I linked to above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't working: I can still acces the folders and all of the files in them.

Comment: If you run the scripts manually (by double clicking on them) does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work either.

Comment: I also tried "Run as Administrator" but nothing changes.

Comment: That's very odd that the scripts don't work... Are the scripts in the same directory as the folder you want to lock (but not in the folder you want to lock)? Try running the command in the script to lock the folder in a CMD window and then try to access the folder. Then try the unlock script and try to access the folder.

Comment: * Are the scripts in the same directory as the folder you want to lock (but not in the folder you want to lock)?* No, I didn't understand that

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Thanks very much for the bounty. Did you also get the scripts to run at specific times? Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped.